# can I assign a variable in a graphql playground to the result of a mutation

Tags: graphql, apollo

If I have a mutation with 2 fields:

```
type Mutation {
  createSimulation(
    name: String
    simulators: [AvailableSimulators!]!
    timeToLiveInMS: Int
  ): Simulation!
  create(
    simulationID: ID!
    simulator: AvailableSimulators!
    type: String!
    attributes: KeyValuePair
  ): CreateResult!
}
```

When I run the mutation in the graphql applo server playground, I need a value from the return of `createSimulation` in a call to `create`:

[image]

Can I somehow assign a variable that I can use in `create`?

Comment: mutations are guaranteed to be called/resolved sequentially then `create` resolver can access earlier mutation result by `parent` (1st) arg

Comment: check [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/462).

Answer (score 0):

Not part of the GraphQL standard. Should handle this in the resolver in the backend. It will depend on the technology used, but in most of the technologies you can use results from previous resolvers or call resolvers manually.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should send 2 requests to handle it. The client-side should request `createSimulation` first to get a response then request another request to `create` mutation with that UUID.